# Error when overwriting hard drive with terminal

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, error

```
Tituss-MBP:~ tituswong$ diskutil secureErase freespace 0 /dev/disk1
Started erase on disk1 Macintosh HD
Creating a temporary file
Securely erasing a file
Creating a secondary temporary file
Mounting disk
Error: -69847: Couldn't create temporary file
Underlying error: 1: POSIX reports: Operation not permitted
```

This was the error. I tried sudo but it didn't work. I'm using OS X El Captain anyone know how to fix this please?

Comment: are you booting from the same drive you are working on?

Comment: yeah is there something I can do

Comment: I think you should boot from another device to be able to complete the operation on the drive.

Comment: So how exactly do I achieve that, the way I'm doing it is from this article btw -- http://www.macworld.com/article/1139688/os-x/erasefreespace.html

Comment: And it didn't say I needed to do this kind of stuff

Comment: The linked article explains how to erase a partition (on an external drive), not the whole disk as you did. Can you still boot into the recovery partition with Cmd-R/Cmd-Opt-R?

Comment: Well I'm just erasing the free space not the whole disk, I tried doing Cmd-R but in disk utilities there was no erase free space option only erase the whole disk

Comment: I hope that you had current up-to-date backups before you started as stated in the article.

Comment: true so how do I get rid of the error

Comment: Have you tried running the same command just with "sudo" in front.. i.e. run "sudo diskutil secureErase freespace 0 /dev/disk1"?

Comment: yeah it just gave me the same error but immediately

Comment: K i guess no one knows